# Bootstrap images not the same size

Tags: html, image, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with Bootstrap css. I have a panels with header, body and footer. The body contains an image. Each of the images have been resized to the same 700px width and 450px height. Yet the panels end up different sizes with the footer not being aligned to each other.

How can this be fixed?

.cshtm code:

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Visual Similarity Duplicate Image Finder
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="portfolio-item.html">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-blog img-hover" src="@ViewBag.AccreditationImage2" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <p>Accreditation test Progress: 10%</p>
                <p>Version: 5.5.0.1</p>
                <p>Vendor: MindGems, Inc.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the ubiquitous image:
[image]

**UPDATE**

It turns out the natural height of the images are indeed different even though they were all resized the same. Anyway, how can I force the images in the panel to all be the same size?

Comment: Are you sure they are 700x450? They don't look squashed which they would have to be to appear smaller

Comment: You should inspect the pictures with e.g. Chrome Developer Tools and look if the _Natural Size_ of the 3 images isn't different.

Comment: @pbaldauf Ok, thanks for that. The Natural Sizes (Heights) are indeed different. See update to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't tell what is happening in your case specifically without seeing the css but you should just be able to set the height attribute on the image or container:

```
<style>
.panel-body {
    height : 450px
}
</style>
```

or:

```
<style>
   .panel-body img {
        height : 450px
    }
</style>
```